# Cannot open or update iPhoto

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, photos.app, launchpad, versions

I bought a used Macbook Pro running macOS Sierra.
It came after the previous owners reset it and installed the iLife pack (iPhoto, iMovie and GarageBand). I couldn't use those apps since it came with Mac OS X 10.9, and those apps versions were to low to use on macOS Sierra.

I had a problem updating GarageBand and iMovie, but I managed to do that after uninstalling those and re-installing them from the Mac App Store. The problem is with iPhoto. I can't open it or uninstall it. I only see this in the Launchpad:

[image]

When I click it I get a message saying that I need to update it, but I can't because according to the Mac App Store, it is not available on my local App Store.

What can I do in order to install it?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, is there a reason why you still want to use iPhoto instead of the Photos app? iPhoto was discontinued in April 2015 and has not appeared on the Mac App Store since. If you have an old iPhoto library, Photos can convert it to a Photos photo library.

Answer (score 3):

As you know, since the previous owners installed a version of the iLife pack you couldn't run on macOS Sierra, you've had to update the individual apps to their current versions.

Where you've fallen down a little, is that while you could install current versions of GarageBand and iMovie, there is **no current version** of iPhoto as it was superseded by the launch of the Photos app. More specifically, iPhoto was discontinued in April 2015 and has not appeared on the Mac App Store since.

Instead, what you need to do is use the Photos app. This should be on your MacBook Pro as it would've been installed as part of macOS Sierra. By default it should be on your Dock, but if it isn't you should be able to find it within your Applications folder.

If you have an old iPhoto library, Photos can convert it to a Photos photo library.

For more information, refer to [Photos Help](https://help.apple.com/photos/mac/1.2/).

Comment: Just to add to this good answer: to stop iPhoto from asking to update, just delete it from the applications folder.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try opening it inside the `/Applications/` folder
2. Downgrade from macOS Sierra to an older version of OS X
3. Open it via the Terminal. Type this line in the terminal and hit enter: `/Applications/iPhoto.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhoto &`

> **Caution:** It is not recommend to use both versions and the same time.
>   There is no reason not to use Photos starting with macOS High Sierra
>   later this year.

Comment: What do you mean by 'both versions'? both versions of what?

Comment: 1. The Photos app in the application folder looks just like in the launchpad. 2. I don't want to downgrade my macOS version. 3. I rather opening it using the normal way.

Comment: Well macOS comes with "Photos", the new "iPhoto" app from Apple. That's the reason why iPhoto is discontinued. To use it, you need to hack around or downgrade.